Base address of HttpClient not been assigned anymore on Blazor Web App
The code shown here works in an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Blazor server-side project, but it is not working in a Blazor Web App built with "Interactive render mode: Server" and "Interactivity location: Global"  (The app will not start with the base address selected, which should be https://localhost:7122/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F ).
I read this article on Microsoft documents but I hope I don't have to go that route and that there is a simpler solution cause my projects are all server side only.
program.cs
    builder.Services
           .AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient 
                                { 
                                    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7122/")

                            });


Detail "is not working". What render mode and where do you register this ?

@Henk Holterman I updated the  question.  rendermode InteractiveServer  the app works fine but the base address is not set anymore as it is in the other  Blazor Server Side app in the same solution

How many program.cs files in your solution?

@Henk Holterman  In the solution there are 2 totaly separated projects with program.cs one is the Blazor Web App and the other is the SSR but they don't cross any reference at all, just share some common libraries and components.

As the document said,  for client-side rendering (CSR), which includes Interactive WebAssembly components and Auto components that have adopted CSR, calls are made with a preconfigured HttpClient registered in the Program file of the client project (BlazorApp.Client):
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp =>
    new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration["FrontendUrl"] ?? "https://localhost:5002")
    });

So if you are using the server-side rendering (SSR currently you are using), which includes prerendered and interactive Server components, prerendered WebAssembly components, and Auto components that are prerendered or have adopted SSR, calls are made with an HttpClient registered in the Program file of the server project.
Like below:
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("localtest", httpClient =>
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7047");

});

Usage:
@page "/"
@inject IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.
 
@code{

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("localtest");
        var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(
            "WeatherForecast");
  

        if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            using var contentStream =
                await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            
        }
    }


}

Result:


All I need is that when the app is deployed it will start with the address "https://mycompany.com..."
That is all. It was working fine before "Blazor Web App" now it is not. I understood your answer up to the Usage: but where does the method  "protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()" goes ? and does it need to be called for every page ?

Firstly , you need clearly what's your question, the httpclient is used to send the request inside this blazor application to other application.  The method I have used is just a test example about how you could use the httpclient to send the request. All I need is that when the app is deployed it will start with the address "mycompany.com..." That is all, if you just want to set the domain for this blazor web app, this is not related with the codes.

Ok. The solution also has a previous "Blazor Server App" project and the code in my question  works fine on it. In development it always open on "localhost:7122" and when deployed on "mycompany.com".  The  new  "Blazor Web App" project  was created using "Interactive render mode: Server" and "Interactivity location: Global"  but the original code that is on my question is now ignored. How can it be implement on the new project to achieve the same result as in the previous project ?

By using my new codes, using the         var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("localtest");         var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(             "WeatherForecast"); could  achieve the same thing. Modify the program.cs codes with your new url inside here httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7047");

This is blazor component codes, you could put it inside the component, please check my update codes.
